# RTMPSrc to v4l2sink

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to receive a rtmp-stream and create a pipe with v4l2sink as output

```
 gst-launch rtmpsrc location="rtmp://localhost/live/test" ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,format=(fourcc)YUY2" ! videorate ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

But I get only a green screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq9oqi9m62c5afo/screencast1422465570.webm?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now It works:

```
gst-launch rtmpsrc location="rtmp://localhost/live/test" ! decodebin2 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,format=(fourcc)YUY2" ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline is telling GStreamer to treat encoded, muxed RTMP data as YUV video buffers.

Instead you need to parse, demux, and decode the video part of the RTMP data.  I don't have a sample stream to test on, but you may be able to just use decodebin (which in GStreamer 0.10 was called decodebin2 for whatever reason).  You'll also want to reorder the videorate to be before the framerate caps, so it knows what to convert to.

Wild stab in the dark:

```
gst-launch rtmpsrc location="rtmp://localhost/live/test" ! decodebin2 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,format=(fourcc)YUY2" ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Comment: What platform are you running on?  Do you have an h264 decoder installed?  Run "gst-inspect | grep 264" and report what you have.

Comment: You're going to want to go into your package manager and see if you're missing any gstreamer packages.  Probably related to libav or ffmpeg.  Maybe gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.  You don't have an h264 video decoder installed.

Comment: I've installed all gstreamer plugins and all libavcodecs but the error is still there. If I install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg it says that there is no Installation candidate. (Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: I dunno what package it would be in either of those, or maybe they decided not to include it for some reason.